# Anyway to make Visual Studio ignore the script tag and assume anything in a script tag is html?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a lot of templates that are enclosed within script tags. They are pure html, but Visual Studio grays them out. I don't have any in-line Javascript so if Visual Studio simply ignored the script tag and treated the contents inside as it would a normal html document would be really nice. I've grown accustomed to CSS class intellisense and nice code formatting.

This is a long shot, anyway this is possible? Right now I'm marking up my HTML then putting it within the script tag, but was hoping for a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can insert a space after the opening bracket of the opening SCRIPT tag to enable HTML IDE support and when your done, just remove the space.

```
< script>
 ^leave space
 <div>HTML is supported</div>
</script>

<script>
 ^no space
 <div>HTML is NOT supported here</div>
</script>
```